# Twitter Bootstrap alert close does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I use Bootstrap 3.0.3 and JQuery 2.0.3

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Encoding" content="gzip" />
    <meta http-equiv="Accept-Encoding" content="gzip, deflate" />
    <title>@L("CONTROL_PANEL") | @ViewBag.Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta content="L" />
    @Styles.Render("~/content/admin/css")
    <link type="text/css" href="/Content/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
    @RenderSection("css", false)
</head>
<body>
    <section id="container">
        <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="title">
                <span>@L("CONTROL_PANEL")</span>
            </div>
        </header>
        <aside class="sidebar">
            <menu class="fisrt">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-tachometer"></i>
                        @L("PANEL")
                    </a>
                    <span class="separator"></span>
                </li>
            </menu>
            <menu class="second">
                @RenderSection("second_menu", false)
            </menu>
        </aside>
        <menu class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#"><span>Панель</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Новости</span></a></li>
        </menu>
        <section class="main-content">
            <div class="panel panel-dark">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">@ViewBag.PanelTitle</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="content">
                        @{
                            if (this.TempData["Success"] != null)
                            {
                                <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                                    <a href="#" class="close close-sm" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">
                                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <h4>
                                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> @L("SUCCESS")
                                    </h4>
                                    <p>@this.TempData["Success"]</p>
                                </div>
                            }

                            if (this.TempData["Error"] != null)
                            {
                            <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                                <button type="button" class="close close-sm" data-dismiss="alert">
                                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                </button>
                                <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.

                            </div>
                            }
                        }
                        <div>
                            @RenderBody()
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <footer>
            Время генерации страницы @TempData["Time"]
        </footer>
    </section>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/js")

    <!-- the jScrollPane script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("js", false)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $(window).load(function () {
                $(".content > div").mCustomScrollbar({
                    theme: "dark-thick",
                    advanced: {
                        autoScrollOnFocus: false,
                        updateOnContentResize: true
                    }
                });


            });
        })(jQuery);   
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I try close message, I get error

> TypeError: elem.getAttribute is not a function.
>
> elem.getAttribute( name ) :   jquery-2.0.3.js (строка 1707)

**Update**

I don't know Why but if change Jquery from NuGet to google start work.

Comment: can you post your full code?

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/86G4Z/2/

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know Why but if change Jquery from NuGet to google start work.

Google offers you the latest jQuery 1.x maybe. Before you used 2.0.3. Bootstrap only supports the 1.x release. (jQuery 2.x drops support for IE8 and Bootstrap still support this).

See also: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started. The basic example template includes `https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js` which offers version 1.10.2.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.0.3/bower.json shows you  Bootstrap 3.0.3 requires >= 1.9.0